# How to count rows based on date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table of dates:

[image]

I want to display how many rows by counting the rows between 2019-06-30 to 2020-03-30 base on the table? the output should be 10 rows. I tried

```
SELECT ln.datestart,
       ln.loanid,
       col.IDNo,
       ls.LoanID,
       max(CAST(col.DateOR AS date)) AS lastpayment,
       COUNT(ls.loanid) AS rowcount
FROM Collections AS col
INNER JOIN LoanSchedules AS ls ON ls.LoanID = col.IDNo
INNER JOIN Loans AS ln ON ln.LoanID = ls.LoanID
WHERE ls.DatePayment BETWEEN ln.DateStart AND max(col.DateOR)
GROUP BY ln.loanid,
         col.IDNo,
         ls.LoanID,
         ln.datestart
```

but it returns an error saying :

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

ps: `ln.datestart` is from another table that records the 1st payment schedule of each client. i use `max(dateor)` from an another table to know the last date of the payment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `having` clause while filtering with aggregated columns,

```
select ls.DatePayment, ln.datestart,ln.loanid,col.IDNo, ls.LoanID, max(CAST(col.DateOR as date)) as 
lastpayment,
COUNT(ls.loanid) as rowcount

from Collections as col
inner join LoanSchedules as ls 
on ls.LoanID = col.IDNo
inner join Loans as ln
on ln.LoanID = ls.LoanID
group by ls.DatePayment, ln.loanid,col.IDNo,ls.LoanID,ln.datestart
having ls.DatePayment between ln.DateStart and max(col.DateOR)
```

Comment: it gives me an error: Column 'LoanSchedules.DatePayment' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Then use the column on the select and group by clause.  Edited the query, please use it

Comment: thanks. I will find it myself. I don't know what exactly should I do but it is a great help.

Answer (score 0):

it's not crystal clear to me what the result you want to achieve is, but I guess you need to use the apply operator. I tried to reproduce your case and here you have the result:

```
create table #LOANS(
             LoanId           char(11) not null
            ,DatePayment      date not null
            ,PrincipalPayment numeric(11,2) not null
            ,InterestPayment  numeric(11,2) not null
            ,TotalPayment     numeric(11,2) not null
)

insert into #LOANS (LoanId, DatePayment, PrincipalPayment, InterestPayment, TotalPayment)
            values ('B 1905.0005', '2019-06-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-07-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-08-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-09-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-10-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-11-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2019-12-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2020-01-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2020-02-29', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2020-03-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2020-04-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')
                  ,('B 1905.0005', '2020-05-30', '5833.33', '2106.67', '7490.00')

select *
from   #LOANS l
       outer apply(select   COUNT(*) as rowNr
                   from     #LOANS ll
                   where    ll.LoanId = l.LoanId
                        and ll.DatePayment between '2019-06-30' and '2020-03-30'
                   group by LoanId) c
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxpc.png

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a hard to follow.  You show one table of data, but your query references three tables.  I'm pretty sure, though, that you can use a window function to do what you want.  It is just unclear *which* window function you want.  I think:

```
SELECT datestart, loanid, cIDNo, LoanID,
       COUNT(*) AS rowcount
FROM (SELECT ln.datestart, ln.loanid, col.IDNo, ls.LoanID, ls.DatePayment,
             MAX(CAST(col.DateOR AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY ln.datestart, ln.loanid, col.IDNo, ls.LoanID) as max_DateOR
      FROM Collections col JOIN
           LoanSchedules ls
           ON ls.LoanID = col.IDNo JOIN
           Loans ln
           ON ln.LoanID = ls.LoanID
     ) x
WHERE DatePayment BETWEEN ln.DateStart AND max_DateOR
GROUP BY loanid, IDNo, LoanID, datestart;
```

This assumes that you are looking for the maximum based on the four `group by` keys.